# Checked out siddhi code, & ran mvn eclipse:eclipse throws error at <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, pom.xml, siddhi

I find it really odd that a project like siddhi wont build right out of the box, I wonder what I am missing.

To start with I just need way to import siddhi into eclipse, and it won't show me any projects when I choose `Import Existing Projects`. If I import from file system, it show a whole bunch of errors and I cannot run simple stuff like `Call and Type`. Really crappy.

Out of all that I googled, I installed maven, and am trying to follow [maven eclipse configuration](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/)

When I run `sudo mvn eclipse:eclipse`, I get the following error

```
~/Development/workinprogress/siddhi$ sudo mvn eclipse:eclipse
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.wso2.cep:cep-parent:3.1.0 (/home/jsiddharth/Development/workinprogress/siddhi/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.wso2.carbon:carbon-products:pom:4.2.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 22, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Line 22 has

```
<parent>^M
    <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>^M
    <artifactId>carbon-products</artifactId>^M
    <version>4.2.0</version>^M
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>^M
</parent>^M
```

I ran mvn eclipse:eclipse from the siddhi folder where pom.xml exists. Now where will I find `../../pom.xml`. It seems like a really silly bug. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does it build without eclipse support? i.e. `mvn clean install`

Comment: No, the damn thing wont build since the root pom.xml refers to some silly ../../pom.xml. Seems like a idiot of a bug.

Comment: Maybe ask the siddhi guys directly? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/siddhi-user The newest siddhi seems to be 3.1.0 is that the one in maven?

Comment: There are barely any conversations happening here, I wonder if anyone is around to help.

Comment: There is actually a file at `../../pom.xml` in the svn repo: http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk08/products/pom.xml

Comment: Is the checkout procedure documented somewhere.. checking out the carbon folder seems silly and unrequired.

Comment: `svn checkout http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/siddhi2 siddhi` (from http://siddhi.sourceforge.net/source-repository.html)

Comment: This checkout is stuck at a time, does not move ahead.. I tried this before.

Comment: svn checkout is stuck, this really sucks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly the source path at the [website](http://siddhi.sourceforge.net/source-repository.html) is wrong. The link mentioned is

> http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/siddhi2

It is actually

> http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/siddhi

I checked this code out using `svn co http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/siddhi siddhi` and then ran `chmod 777 -R siddhi`. After this I ran `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, imported the projects to eclipse and its all green now.

Finally... thanks @mb21